# Angularjs - attribute equal to value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does someone know why if I do 'drawStock="drawStock' like

```
<tr ng-repeat="icl in ic.internal_consumption_lines" drawStock="drawStock(locator_id, product_id)" ...></tr>
```

And then in my script

```
scope: { 
...
drawStock: "&",
...
},
template:{
...
<span>{{drawStock({locator_id:ic.internal_consumption_lines[index].transaction.locator.id, product_id:ic.internal_consumption_lines[index].transaction.product.id})}}</span>
...
...
$scope.drawStock = (lid, pid) ->
for i of $scope.product_stocks
  if $scope.product_stocks[i].locator_id == lid
    if $scope.product_stocks[i].product_id == pid
      return $scope.product_stocks[i].stock
```

The drawStock function won't display the stock, but if I change the attribute for a different name than the value, let's say something like 'drawstock="drawStock(...' it works...:

```
<tr ng-repeat="icl in ic.internal_consumption_lines" drawstock="drawStock(locator_id, product_id)" ...></tr>
```

And then in my script

```
scope: { 
...
drawstock: "&",
...
},
template:{
...
<span>{{drawstock({locator_id:ic.internal_consumption_lines[index].transaction.locator.id, product_id:ic.internal_consumption_lines[index].transaction.product.id})}}</span>
...
...
$scope.drawStock = (lid, pid) ->
for i of $scope.product_stocks
  if $scope.product_stocks[i].locator_id == lid
    if $scope.product_stocks[i].product_id == pid
      return $scope.product_stocks[i].stock
```

Comment: What is the difference between the upper snippet and the lower snippet ? They seem identical to me...

Comment: drawStock="drawStock vs drawstock="drawStock, watch the upper case "S", which makes the difference between the attribute and the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **[the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_matching-directives)**:

> Angular **normalizes** an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) **normalized** name (e.g. `ngModel`). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using [dash-delimited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Computers) attributes on DOM elements (e.g. `ng-model`).
>
> The **normalization** process is as follows:
>
> 1. Strip `x-` and `data-` from the front of the element/attributes.
> 2. Convert the `:`, `-`, or `_`-delimited name to `camelCase`.

---

In your case, when Angular sees `drawStock: "&"` it understands it as `drawStock: "&drawStock"`, which misleads it into looking for `draw-stock` in your HTML.
And because there is no `draw-stock` (but only `drawStock`) in your HTML, it does not work !

If you want to use the camelCase form in your HTML (e.g. because you find it more readable) and since HTML is case-insensitive, you should either (1) explicitely specify the attribute's name or (2) use lowercase in your directive. E.g.:

HTML: `<tr ... drawStock="...">   // (this is camelCase)`

Directive (1): `scope: { drawStock: '&drawstock' }   // (1st camelCase, 2nd lowercase)`
Directive (2): `scope: { drawstock: '&' }            // (this is lowercase)`
<sub>(both directives above refer to the "camelCased" HTML attribute)</sub>